# R violin plot fill color quantiles in ggplot or plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, quantile

Is it possible to have quantiles filled with different colors in the violin plot?

Using the iris data:

```
require(ggplot2)
    ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_violin(draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))
```

we get the following violin plot where I would like to have the upper quantile filed red and the lower quantile filled blue

[image: Violin plots]

And if so if one know how to do this in plotly that would be even better!

Comment: I don't know how to do this with `geom_violin` but I use `ggridges::stat_density_ridges()` a lot for things like this when I want color/fill. See the section Stats>Quantile lines and coloring by quantiles or probabilities here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html